# Obtener valor para una celda de tabla a partir de consulta SQL. MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Necesito calcular el sub_total en la tabla.El precio del producto esta en una tabla distinta y quiero que a partir de las unidades y el precio calcule el sub_total de forma automática sin tener que crear una consulta SQL en un formulario. Como debería hacerlo?
Tabla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitaría hacer lo siguiente: Con el código del producto obtener el precio de este en la tabla correspondiente. Despues, con el precio y las unidades calcular el Sub_Total y guardar el resultado en este campo.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que se pueda sin SQL, pero ¿Has probado con Campo Calculado?

Comment: El problema es que no se si a partir de campo calculado se puede acceder a otras tablas.

Comment: En consultas sí, con un Dbúsq, pero en tablas creo que no. Y volverías a lo mismo, que necesitas tener una consulta SQL donde mirarlo.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero en un subformulario creo que se puede hacer referencia a un campo de un formulario padre para hacer calculos en un campo calculado.
Podrías probar si es tu caso en cuanto a la estructura.
Si lo que vas a hacer es guardar una especie de factura, en una tercera tabla, creo que se recomienda guarda el resultado del calculo directamente para que cada vez que se hace una consulta a esa tabla no se tenga que recalcular todo el rato.